# Override category permalink to match old non-WordPress links?

Tags: permalinks

I am migrating a currently static website to WordPress.

The pages (I am using pages, not posts and categories) have the following structure:

```
 Products (parent page)
 - Product 1 (child-page)
 - Product 2 (child-page)
 - Product 3 (child-page)
```

Custom permalink is:

```
example.com/%category%/%postname%/
```

Generated links are:

```
example.com/products
example.com/products/product-1
example.com/products/product-2
example.com/products/product-3
```

Now for SEO reasons, the old link for Product 2 was

```
example.com/my-super-products/product-2
```

How can I override the category for this page without creating a new parent page with the desired name?

Comment: your products are child pages of a parent page, how are categories involved? your permalinks setting has no relation to pages, only posts.

Comment: I have pages, not posts and categories. The permalink does influence pages as well.

Comment: the title and content of your question both say category, so what you're actually asking is how can a child page appear to have a different parent page without that parent page actually existing?

Comment: True, I mentioned categories, as the permalink is using the term categories. But you rephrased my question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rewrite_API will let you modify the slug and URI at many levels. You might need to come up with a custom page template for Product 2 that assigns the '/my-super-products' slug, but this should work for you.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API